# Assign a onclick function with static value

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, getelementbyid

I use a code like this:

```
<div id="div2" onclick="alert(0)" >On click must return 2</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="changeClick(2);">On Click change return of DIV2 click to 2</div>
```

.

```
function changeClick(i){
 document.getElementById('div'+i).onclick = function(){alert(i)};
 i=9;
}
```

but I want to respond to the click 2 and not 9 like:

```
document.getElementById('div'+i).onclick = function (){alert(2);};
```

(i=9) is for simulate a real condition of my real function, because (i) increment in a loop for change many div.
Is not possible use of if or switch statement.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Malik ok sure, I published a simpler version

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood your question the solution might be

```
(function ()
{
  var i=1;    
  document.getElementById('div'+i).onclick = function (){alert(i);};
})();
i=9
```

Please check the link below
https://jsfiddle.net/ankurshah32/tawfdsk8/

Comment: I published a simpler version

Answer (score 0):

You could use an 'if' statement inside of your function that checks the value of 'i', or if there are multiple values to check use a 'switch' statement.

```
function changeClik(i) {
    if (i === 2) {
        document.getElementById('div' + i).onclick = function() {alert(2);}
    }
```

Comment: Ah! thanks for elaborating on your code. I can see that my if statement won't help you much...sorry I tried.